# A question about cut sets in posets and comparable elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**4.3 Definition** Let A be a partially ordered class. Two elements x and y in A are said to be comparable if either x $\leq$  y or y$\leq$ x..

**4.7 Definition** If A is a partially ordered class, then a cut of A is pair **(L, U)** of nonempty subclasses of A with the following properties:

i) L∩U=ØandL∪U=A.

ii) Ifx∈Land y$\leq$x,theny∈L.

iii) Ifx∈Uand y$\geq$x,theny∈U.

**My question is:**
By 4.3 can I use x $\leq$ y instead of y $\leq$ x in (i i)

When I look at (i i), I suspect it is a chain in A.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change $y\le x$ to $x\le y$ in (ii). The condition is intended to ensure that the set $L$ is downward-closed, meaning that if some element of $A$ is in $L$, so is every element of $A$ below (i.e., less than or equal to) that element. In other words, if $x\in L$, then every $y\le x$ is also in $L$. $L$ is in general not a chain in $A$. An example may help.

> **Example:** Let $A=\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$, and for $\langle x_0,y_0\rangle,\langle x_1,y_1\rangle\in A$ let $\langle x_0,y_0\rangle\le\langle x_1,y_1\rangle$ if and only if $x_0\le x_1$ and $y_0\le y_1$. Let $L=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in A:x,y\le 0\}$, the closed third quadrant of the plane, and let $U=A\setminus L$.
>
> If $\langle a,b\rangle\in L$, and $\langle x,y\rangle\le\langle a,b\rangle$, then $x\le a\le 0$ and $y\le b\le 0$, so $\langle x,y\rangle\in L$, and $L$ satisfies (ii). It’s clear that $L$ and $U$ satisfy (i). Finally, suppose that $\langle a,b\rangle\in U$ and $\langle a,b\rangle\le\langle x,y\rangle$. Since $\langle a,b\rangle\notin L$, either $a>0$ or $b>0$. If $a>0$, then $x\ge a>0$, so $\langle x,y\rangle\notin L$ and hence $\langle x,y\rangle\in U$. Similarly, if $b>0$, then $y\ge b>0$, and again $\langle x,y\rangle\in U$. Thus, $U$ satisfies (iii), and $\langle L,U\rangle$ is a cut in $A$.
>
> And $L$ is definitely not a chain, since $\langle -1,0\rangle,\langle 0,-1\rangle\in L$, $\langle -1,0\rangle\not\le\langle 0,-1\rangle$, and $\langle 0,-1\rangle\not\le\langle -1,0\rangle$.

Comment: I did not change it ,thanks. I guess cut sets have little to do with comparable elements...

Comment: Thanks for your example.It clarifies how to do these things. There are no examples of how to do them in Pinter’s A book of Set Theory in chapter 4

Comment: @HomerSimpson: You’re welcome.

Comment: Let f:A->B
One last question: would a cut in B imply f(x)$\in$ L then every f(y)<f(x) is too?

Comment: @HomerSimpson: If $f:A\to B$ is order-preserving, $\langle L,U\rangle$ is a cut in $B$, and $f(x)\in L$, then $f(y)\in L$ for all $y\le x$.

Comment: so what you’re saying in this case if  $ f(x) \in L$ and y$\leq$ x then f(y) $\in $ L

Comment: @HomerSimpson: Yes, provided that $f$ is order-preserving; otherwise all bets are off! And $L$ doesn’t actually have to be the lower part of a cut: it just has to be downward-closed, meaning that if $y\le x\in L$, then $y\in L$.

Comment: @HomerSimpson: I’m afraid that I’m not sure what you’re asking; I’m pretty sure that you’ve misunderstood something, but I can’t tell what. Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are partially ordered by $\le_A$ and $\le_B$, respectively, and $f:A\to B$ is order-preserving, meaning that if $x,y\in A$ and $x\le_A y$, then $f(x)\le_B f(y)$. Suppose further that $L\subseteq B$ is downward closed, meaning that if $x,y\in B$, $y\in L$, and $x\le_By$, then $x\in L$. Finally, suppose that $x,y\in A$, $x\le_Ay$, and $f(y)\in L$. THEN $f(x)\in L$.

Comment: @HomerSimpson: The $L$ in these comments has absolutely nothing to do with the one in my example; it’s simply some downward-closed set in $B$, which is some partially ordered set.

Comment: @M Scott Thanks for putting up with my confusion  I thought L had to be defined by some set.